# apache2 - ssl virtual host does not execute cgi scripts

Tags: apache2, openssl, virtualhost, apache2-module

I have the following virtual host configuration

```
<VirtualHost petyo.net:443>
    ServerAdmin m@petyo.net

    DocumentRoot /home/ren/public/
    <Directory "/home/ren/pubic/*">
            Options +ExecCGI Indexes
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
            AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .py .pl
    </Directory>


    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/petyo.net-ssl_errors.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel debug

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/petyo.net_access.log combined


    #   SSL Engine Switch:
    #   Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.
    SSLEngine on
    .....
```

I.e. an ssl enabled website, however it does not run the cgi scripts.

While I have exactly the same configuration (without the ssl stuff), which runs the cgi scripts with no problem at all. 
No other virtual hosts are enabled!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typo:

```
<Directory "/home/ren/pubic/*">
                         ^---missing L?
```

Comment: :( I feel ashamed. Sorry fixed now !

Comment: No worries. I used to work in a public library, and you wouldn't believe how many email signatures/press releases went out as "pubic library"...

Comment: There's a [campaign to clean up Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167342) by removing these typo-related questions, we could really use your help! Would you mind pitching in a little by casting a close vote on this question?